# What is the default of postgresql sslfactory behaviour

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

What is the default of postgresql sslfactory behaviour

I have searched online and could not find an answer
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/ssl-client.html

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-factory.html

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#ssl

Which one Does it use  ?

Im using Amazon AWS postgresql RDS

Comment: Are you using version 91?

Comment: @jjanes the driver client version is 42.3.3

Comment: Then that is the version you should read.  [`The default SSL Socket factory is the LibPQFactory`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, to Jjanes

"Then that is the version you should read. The default SSL Socket factory is the org.postgresql.ssl.jdbc4.LibPQFactory"